# What are those cache.js and compilation-mappings files

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

Recently I received a package with web page. I see inside (beside normal html and js files) there are some JS files. It looks like this:

```
4A3674A3247236B3C8294D2378462378.cache.js
FE728493278423748230C48234782347.cache.js
compilation-mappings.txt
```

Inside .js files I see Javascript which is obfuscated or minified. Inside `compilation-mappings.txt` the `cache.js` are referenced. Are these files generated by some kind of WEB IDE? Unfortunately I have  no chance to get information how this wep page was developed.

Comment: Looks like they're from https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/source/browse/android/assets/www/?repo=showcase&r=ae1e43c2161b7b11e1b0b5877245844d6f9ff924#www%2Fshowcase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a web project coded in Java and compiled to JS using the [GWT project](http://www.gwtproject.org/) tools.

GWT compiler does a lot of the work you would have to do manually when coding JS by hand, and some other tasks which are almost impossible in a normal JS project: obfuscate, compress, death-code removal, different optimization per browser, renaming of the scripts, code splitting, etc.

What you have in your app is the result of this compilation:

1. First you should have a unique `index.html` file, because GWT is used to produce RIA (Rich Internet Applications) also known as SPI (Single Page Interface).
2. The unique html file should have a reference to a javascript file named `application_name.nocache.js`. Note the .nocache. part, meaning that the web server should set the appropriate headers, so as it is not cached by proxies nor browsers. This file is very small becaust it just have the code to identify the browser and ask for the next javascript file.
3. This first script knows which `NNNN.cache.js` have to load each browser. The NNNN prefix is a unique number which is generated when the app is compiled, and it is different for each browser. GWT supports 6 different browser platforms, so normally you would have 6 files like this. Note the .cache. part of the name, meaning that this files could be cached for ever. They are large files because have all the code of your application.

So the normal workflow of your app is that the browser ask for the `index.html` file which can be cached. This file has the script tag to get the small start script `applicaton.nocache.js` which should be always requested to the server. It has just the code for loading the most recent permutation for your browser `NNNN.cache.js` which will be downloaded cached in your browser for ever.

You have more info about this stuff [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What%27s_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames)

The goals of this naming convention is that the next time the user goes to the app, it will be in cache the `index.html` and `NNNN.cache.js` files, asking only for the `application.nocache.js` which is really small. It guarantees that the user loads always the most recent version of the app, that the browser will download just once the code of your app, that proxies or cache devices do not break your app when releasing a new version, etc.

Said that, it is almost impossible to figure out what the code does inspecting the javascript stuff because of the big obfuscation. You need the original .java files to understand the code or make modifications.

Comment: Other elements fits my package. Thank you. I am after my first HelloGWT project and I see my SDK created NNN.cache.html instead of NNN.cache.js. What is the reason? Some other GWT version?

Comment: There are different linkers you can use in GWT. The default one puts all the js inside an .html file and loads it in an iframe, it is done in this way so as it runs in a different context. Lately the recomendation is to use the new xiframe linker which produces .js files and they are loaded asynchronously in an iframe. You have to modify your .gwt.xml file to enable it.

Comment: I need to ask yet because I am walking in dark and I will probably need to rewrite this code from scratch. My HelloGWP project (one Button(), one Label()) generates cache.js file about 35kB. In my package I received cache.js about 1MB in size. Is it possible to provide rough estimation how many time takes this implementation (or how many Java lines)? I know this is strange question, but I would like to know if this is like 1 month or 3 months or more (full time project).

Comment: Well, gwt compiler does an amazing work removing unused code, optimizing and compressing it. The javascript size related with the java LOC is not lineal because common stuff is needed from the beginning. Also the size of javascript depends of certain configuration parameters like optimization level, remove stack-trace emulations, class names, use the closure compiler, etc. But as reference, I have an complex application with about 50,000 lines and the .cache files have a size of around 970 KB. I'm using all optimizations when I compile.

Comment: Thanks you for real life example. This gives me some picture.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure, but often a string will be attached to the name of a javascript file so that when a new version is deployed clients will not use a cached version of the old one.

(ie, if you have myScript.js and change it, the browser will say "I already have myScript.js, Idon't need it. If it goes from being myScript1234.js to myScript1235.js the browser will go fetch it)

It is possible the framework in use generated those files as part of it's scheme to handle client side cache issues. Though without knowing more details of what framework they used, there's no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: That makes perfect sens. This looks like some MD5 is added as name with every change.

Comment: I thought that at first, but it would be weird for the MD5 sum to be entirely numeric.

Comment: I just put there totally random numbers from keyboard. But in reality this are alphanumerics. Seems to be GWT as pointed by some users.