# GWT's compilation-mappings file publicly available

Tags: gwt

During a security audit I came across this file in a web server. It is publicly available for unauthenticated users. After doing some research (this url proved very useful [What are those cache.js and compilation-mappings files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794685/what-are-those-cache-js-and-compilation-mappings-files)) I can't seem to find my answer anywhere:

Should this file be available for the public? Does it present a security risk? 
Or on the other hand it has to be publicly available to work out what browser is interacting with the web server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The compilation-mappings file contains the exact same information as the `*.nocache.js` file. It poses no security risk (otherwise, rest assured that it would be produced in another directory).

Google uses it to replace the `*.nocache.js` and do the script selection on the server (with a custom GWT linker and a custom servlet). But it is not used by "standard" GWT setups, so you can safely delete or block it if you'd rather not expose it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, much appreciated - it's all I was asking. Gave you points-up but don't have enough "reputation" for it to show.